# How to determine time when a photo of star trails was taken?

Tags: star, photography, time

I was asked to define a time (most likely the month) and location of the picture below.
[image]

I hope I understood it right that it is the south pole, because we don't see a Polar star in the middle. However, I don't understand how I can know the time.

Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the south pole during winter is an excellent guess. Off the top of my head I can't see a way of going to any greater precision without going through historical records of aurora activity.

Comment: My teacher told me that aurora borealis is not the key here and I need to pay attention to star trails...

Comment: I'm usually wrong about these things, but this image looks to me like it was selected to be impossible to tell *exactly* which month it was taken in. It's sometime in the winter in the southern hemisphere because the sky is dark, so it will be close to June, but I don't see how one can rule out May nor July completely.

Comment: I can't positively identify any of the structures but just left of the top reminds me of the [Ice Cube Neutrino Observatory building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IceCube_Neutrino_Observatory) (and [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUZCY.jpg)) and the thing on the right could be [one of these dishes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ild1m.jpg) (from [here](https://www.coolantarctica.com/Bases/modern_antarctic_bases3.php)), in other words, yes it seems like the South Pole or nearby.

Comment: Hang on, I got a lead. It's not something that you see, but something you don't see. The moon and planets. They spend about 50% of their time in the southern celestial hemisphere, but I don't see any obvious ones here. The brightest line close to the edge is Sirius, with a declination of -16 degrees. Jupiter, mars, venus and the moon will be brighter than that. The next bright stars towards the edge are Spica at -11 and Rigel at -8. I can't find a decent star candidate for what the orange one on the outer edge might be, so I think that's Saturn.

Comment: The rest is a bit tedious - just use some kind of planetarium software to go back and find a period during winter in which there are no planets or moon in the southern sky.

Comment: @Ingolifs about june 10th 2013 would seem to fit the bill.